# Interval of bytes in incoming char*

Tags: c

I am currently implementing a server-client API. In order to minimize the number of messages send between these, I have implemented a message format, where I send a fixed number of bytes (using a char*). The first byte contains a request (given as a single char) and the following 12 bytes are providing a username.

What is the smartest way to extract the username? I know I can simply extract the request using a simple:

```
    char request = message[0]
```

Is there a similar way to extract the remaining bytes in the interval 1-12 using c? Here Im trinking of a solution that does not include having to implement a function that iterates and extract information as I know how to do this using a simple loop.

Comment: This is most basic C knowledge. You probably need `memcpy`.

Comment: I the username is `null-terminated` you can use [strncpy](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcpy.3.html) otherwise you can use [memcpy](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memcpy.3.html)

Comment: If it is a C-string (ends with a NUL byte) then `message+1` is the address of a correct C-string... You may also think of using a structure correctly padded, aligned, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want something like this:

```
char request = message[0];
...
char username[12 + 1];             // + 1 for the string terminator
...
memcpy(username, message + 1, 12);
username[12] = 0;                  // put the string terminator
```

or even simply:

```
strcpy(username, message + 1);
```

provided the username is NUL terminated. The latter aproach is dangerous though because if the message is incorrect, yoo might get a buffer overflow. This kind of weakness has been exploited in real world in the past.

Comment: Hmm that makes sense to me thanks :) I knew about some approach using the strcpy, but as my char* by default is not null terminated I avoided this for now. The memcpy solution I did not know.

Comment: Consider `snprintf(username, sizeof username, "%s", message + 1);` : a "safe" vesion of `strcpy`